# Public property of exported class is using private type error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

> C:\dev\OpenCMS\Website\Frontend\Scripts\libs\sinnovations>tsc
>   sinnovations.listv iewbase.ts --module amd
>   C:/dev/OpenCMS/Website/Frontend/Scripts/libs/sinnovations/sinnovations.listviewb
>   ase.ts(11,5): error TS2025: Public property 'columns' of exported
>   class has or i s using private type 'KnockoutObservableArray'.

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
import ko = require('knockout');

interface Column {
    label: string;
}

var _templateBase = '/Frontend/Templates/ListView/';
class ListViewBase<T> {

    columns: KnockoutObservableArray<Column> = ko.observableArray([]);
    rows: KnockoutObservableArray<T> = ko.observableArray([]); 

    constructor(public templateHeaderRow = _templateBase+'DefaultTableHeaderTemplate', public templateBodyRow = _templateBase + 'DefaultTableRowTemplate') {

    }

    addColumn(column: Column) {
        this.columns.push(column);
    }

    addRow(row: T) {
        this.rows.push(row);
    }

    static configure(templateBase) {
        _templateBase = templateBase;   
    }
}

export = ListViewBase;
```

I understand the error, but dont know how else to get the effect of above. Anyone have a solution to export some interfaces along a class that is exported as export = class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am afraid you need to define the interface in another file. e.g.

a.ts:

```
interface Column {
    label: string;
}
```

and your code :

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./a.ts" />
import ko = require('knockout');


var _templateBase = '/Frontend/Templates/ListView/';
class ListViewBase<T> {

    columns: KnockoutObservableArray<Column> = ko.observableArray([]);
    rows: KnockoutObservableArray<T> = ko.observableArray([]); 

    constructor(public templateHeaderRow = _templateBase+'DefaultTableHeaderTemplate', public templateBodyRow = _templateBase + 'DefaultTableRowTemplate') {

    }

    addColumn(column: Column) {
        this.columns.push(column);
    }

    addRow(row: T) {
        this.rows.push(row);
    }

    static configure(templateBase) {
        _templateBase = templateBase;   
    }
}

export = ListViewBase;
```

Comment: Okay. Guess I just need to get used to defining my interfaces in seperate files. Thanks

Comment: I just have one file  with all our interfaces called *types.ts*

Comment: could you explain why one has to describe it in a separate file? Your suggestion worked for me too, but it seems quite counter-intuitive..