# Typescript: Export instance of class that holds state

Tags: typescript, commonjs

I have the `class` `MyStore` that contains data and state for my JS-application. I want to receive a single instance when importing that class in other files (I am using commonjs a.k.a external modules).

Example:

MyStore.ts

```
class MyStore extends BaseStore {
    private _items;
    getItems() { return _items; }
} 

export = MyStore;
```

OtherFile.ts:

```
import MyStore = require('./MyStore');
MyStore.getItems();
```

this doesn't work as I have to insantiate MyStore in Otherfile.ts

My current solution is to have a static singleton method:

MyStore.ts:

```
private static _instance = new MyStore();
static getInstance(){ return this._instance;}
```

OtherFile.ts

```
import MyStore = require('./MyStore');
MyStore.getInstance().getItems();
```

Is there any better way?

Edit: The reason it is a Typescript class is to allow inheritance (extending baseclass)

Comment: @steve-fenton Sorry, that question is not a duplicate. This is typescript specific. With non typescript components, everything works as expected (can export a normal object)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is a TypeScript question and the question that it was pointed to is JavaScript. They are related but the solution is different.

Comment: Its the private exports bug which will be fixed in the github compiler version (v1.1). In the meantime, interfaces are the workaround: http://bit.ly/1qphDqE

Comment: @GorgiKosev, please add your comment as an answer (if possible, otherwise vote for reopen). Great answer, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I will add it as soon as the duplicate flag is removed.

Comment: Apologies - I suspected the same fix would work - I have re-opened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be simple, right?

```
class MyStore { ... }
// export a single instance
export = new MyStore(...);
```

Unfortunately, typescript 1.0 doesn't allow this. The type of exported values must also be exported from the module. In this case, that defeats the entire point of singletons.

The 1.1 compiler (not officially released yet, but available on GitHub) fixes this.

In the meantime, the workaround is to use declaration merging to export both an interface and an implementation with the same name:

```
class MyStoreImpl implements MyStore {
    private _items;
    getItems() { return this._items; }
}
interface MyStore {
    getItems();
}
var MyStore:MyStore = new MyStoreImpl();
export = MyStore;
```

Comment: great! I had to put the interface in a new file to get this to work tho. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794791/public-property-of-exported-class-is-using-private-type-error-in-typescript