# Public property of exported class has or is using private name

Tags: typescript

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794791/public-property-of-exported-class-is-using-private-type-error-in-typescript) however the exporting doesn't solve my issue for me.

I have the following code snippet, `cloudFoundry.ts`:

```
export var cf = require.__$__nodeRequire<any>('cf-client');

export class CloudFoundry {

    apps: typeof cf.Apps;
    cloudController: typeof cf.CloudController;
    domains: typeof cf.Domains;
    logs: typeof cf.Logs;
    usersUAA: typeof cf.UsersUAA;
    routes: typeof cf.Routes;
    organizations: typeof cf.Organizations;
    spaces: typeof cf.Spaces;
    services: typeof cf.Services;

constructor() {
        // load services with proper token + config
        this.initializeServices();
        return;
    }

    ....

    private initializeServices() {
        ['cloudController', 'apps', 'domains', 'organizations', 'routes', 'spaces', 'services', 'logs','usersUAA'].map(function(_class){
            eval(`this.${_class} = new(cf).${_class.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + _class.slice(1)}(this._endpoint)`);
            eval(`this.${_class}.setToken(this.token)`);
        }, this);
        this.cloudController.getInfo().then((result) => {
            this.usersUAA.setEndPoint(result.authorization_endpoint);
            this.logs.setEndPoint(result.logging_endpoint);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log('ERROR ' + e);
            return;
        });
    }
}
```

Then another file `viewlet.ts`

```
...
import {
    CloudFoundry,
    OauthToken
} from './cloudFoundry';
...
```

However typescript is throwing the following error.

```
cloudFoundry.ts(24,15): Public property 'apps' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(25,26): Public property 'cloudController' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(26,18): Public property 'domains' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(27,15): Public property 'logs' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(28,19): Public property 'usersUAA' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(29,17): Public property 'routes' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(30,24): Public property 'organizations' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(31,17): Public property 'spaces' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
cloudFoundry.ts(32,19): Public property 'services' of exported class has or is using private name 'cf'.
```

I tried the trick that was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794791/public-property-of-exported-class-is-using-private-type-error-in-typescript) by exporting the import and that at least got rid of the error.

```
export var cf = require.__$__nodeRequire<any>('cf-client');
```

But then I got the following issue at runtime...

```
cf is not defined: ReferenceError: cf is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (cloudFoundry.js:41:108)
```

The line is referring to the following.

```
eval("this." + _class + " = new(cf)." + (_class.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + _class.slice(1)) + "(this._endpoint)");
```

Any help would be appreciated for trying to fix this.

Comment: @AngelAngel hmm that didn't work..

Comment: (I'm new in typescript) after reading this -> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307, you may have to be exported cf.xxx to use it? Sorry for my English, I hope to understand me, may have to indicate the type as export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by exporting the import:

```
export var cf = require.__$__nodeRequire<any>('cf-client');
export class CloudFoundry {
    apps: typeof cf.Apps;
    ...
```

and

importing the library when it was used as well.

```
private initializeServices() {
    var cf = require.__$__nodeRequire<any>('cf-client');
    ....
```